# Wildfly 8.2.0 JMS Topic is missing

Tags: java, jms, wildfly, hornetq

I`ve set up an webapplication with Wildfly 8.2.0 Final. Im now trying to create a jms topic and send and receive some messages throught 2 beans.

Bean 1 is my sender/publisher:

```
@Stateless
public class ChatPublisherBean implements ChatPublisherLocal, ChatPublisherRemote {


@JMSConnectionFactory("java:/ConnectionFactory")
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Resource(lookup = "java:global/jms/ChatRoomTopic")
private Topic topic;


//more code ...
```

Bean 2 my receiver/consumer:

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "java:global/jms/ChatRoomTopic",
    messageListenerInterface = MessageListener.class,
    activationConfig = {
            @ActivationConfigProperty(
            propertyName = "destinationType",
            propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(
            propertyName = "destination",
            propertyValue = "java:global/jms/ChatRoomTopic")})
public class ChatReceiverBean implements MessageListener, ChatReceiverLocal, ChatReceiverRemote {


@Inject
private ChatServiceLocal chatService;

@Inject
private ChatPublisherBean jmsConnectionBean;


//more code
```

As you can see i use the automatic resource generation of jms 2.0 (or at least I try) and it works well with the ConnectionFactory cause i use the standard factory there.

The problem now is that when i try to deploy it my topic isnt found properly.
Wildfly gives me this error:

```
19:03:38,187 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "app.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"app.ear\".\"core-ejb.jar\".component.ChatReceiverBean.CREATE is missing [jboss.ra.hornetq-ra]",
"jboss.naming.context.java.comp.app.core-ejb.ChatPublisherBean.env.\"de.app.platform.chat.services.jms.ChatPublisherBean\".topic is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.global.jms.ChatRoomTopic]"
]}
19:03:38,188 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "app.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"app.ear\".\"core-ejb.jar\".component.ChatReceiverBean.CREATE is missing [jboss.ra.hornetq-ra]",
"jboss.naming.context.java.comp.app.core-ejb.ChatPublisherBean.env.\"de.app.platform.chat.services.jms.ChatPublisherBean\".topic is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.global.jms.ChatRoomTopic]"
```

Also there seems to be a problem with the hornetq adapter which is in my standalone.xml declared as the standard:

```
<mdb>
    <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:hornetq-ra}"/>
     <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
 </mdb>
```

Does anyone now what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I always had to create the Topics outside of code.  I have a little script that I run to get them set.  The relevant part is something like:

```
$WILDFLY_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="jms-topic add --topic-address=ChatRoomTopic --entries=java:/jms/ChatRoomTopic
```

later, if you want to remove it:

```
$WILDFLY_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="jms-topic remove --topic-address=ChatRoomTopic
```

This was done in Wildfly 8.2

Comment: unfortunately that isnt working in my case, but thx anyway ;)     maybe another question: do you know why you couldnt create topics in your code?

Comment: What isn't working?  The server must be running to run the commands.  In general you can't create a topic in code - there are no standard API's do to that.